# Поставить переменную в строку Jenkins

Tags: ansible, jenkins

```
withCredentials([
      usernamePassword(credentialsId: '', passwordVariable: 'ldap_ssh_pass', usernameVariable: 'ldap_ssh_user'),
      string(credentialsId: "git-token-inventory", variable: 'TOKEN')]) {


      println 'Execute playbook at'
      echo host
      ansiColor('xterm') {

        env.SCRIPT_RET=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'python3 contechsys/scripts/getdns.py ${host}').trim()
        echo env.SCRIPT_RET

        Результат скрипта 
        kurch

          ansiblePlaybook become: true, colorized: true, credentialsId: '', tags: '${tag}', extras: '-vv --limit ${host}', inventory: 'hosts/exporter.onehost', playbook: 'contechsys/tasks/${env.SCRIPT_RET}.yml'

          // cleanWs()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Пытался обратиться как `$переменная` - без результатов. Пытался как `${переменная}` - аналогично

Как правильно его внести в строку
`playbook:  'contechsys/tasks/${env.SCRIPT_RET}.yml'`,
чтобы получилось `playbook: 'contechsys/tasks/kurch.yml'`?